# Print with Android without settings popup

Tags: android, printing

In my application, when I need to print a picture, I use the following code

```
    PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(context);
    photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
    photoPrinter.printBitmap("example", bitmap);
```

By doing so, Android shows me the settings popup, when I can choose which printer, orientation and all the stuff

Is there a way to bypass this whole step? My application needs to print always with the same settings, and the final user can't have the permission to change anything: he pushes the Print button and the printing begins

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to bypass the print pop up dialog in android.

Comment: I was afraid of that answer. Thanks anyway